# To prove that the following equation has no solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is :

Prove that there are no real numbers $(x,y)$ that satisfy the equation

$$ 13+\ 12[\arctan(x)]=62[\ln(x)]+8[e^x]+4[\arccos(y)] $$

$ [\ ] \text{ denotes the greatest integer function} $

I tried writing the possible values of $\arctan(x), \arccos(y)$ thereby leading to the values of $x$ and $y$. that turned out to be useless.

Can someone help me or is there an alternative approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The LHS and RHS of the equation are both integers (why?).

The RHS is an even integer. Observe the common factor 2 in the RHS.

The LHS, irrespective of the value of [arctan(x)] is an odd integer.

since LHS=RHS, which means, an odd number= an even number..

This is clearly a contradiction.

Hence there are no (x,y) that satisfy the above equation

Comment: Wow.. that's an elegant way of solving the problem.

Comment: Didnt think of it at all!!

Answer (score 4):

$12, 62, 8, 4$ are even, while $13$ is odd.